# Python logging module always uses the same file

Tags: python, logging

I have two logging classes, that should print logs on two different files.

**First class**

```
import logging

class firstLog:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger1")
        logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s.%(msecs)06d:\n%(message)s\n", level=logging.DEBUG,
                            datefmt="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",
                            filename="filename1.log")

    def printlog(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Second class**

```
import logging

class secondLog:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger2")
        logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s.%(msecs)06d:\n%(message)s\n", level=logging.DEBUG,
                            datefmt="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",
                            filename="filename2.log")

    def printlog(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

I instantiate the two classes, but only *filename1.log* is written

```
log1 = firstLog()
log2 = secondLog()

log1.printlog("text1")
log2.printlog("text2")
```

What I obtain is that a new file, called *filename1.log* is created, and contains

```
04/06/2021 08:57:04.000988:
text1
04/06/2021 08:57:04.000990:
text2
```

but I need two separate files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logging.basicConfig()` is only applied once.

If `logging` has been configured already, `basicConfig()` will do nothing unless `force` is set. ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig))

In your case you should get separate loggers with `logging.getLogger(name)` and different names. Then configure the loggers manually.

Comment: You should have a look at the [How-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html). It explains a lot about the concepts of the logging package and how to configure it. You will also see way many developers use `getLogger(__name__)` instead of creating loggers manually.

Answer (score 1):

`logging.basicConfig()` is meant to be run once at your app's startup time, and will configure the root logger.

You will need to configure the two other loggers manually if you need their output to go elsewhere (or maybe configure a "routing" handler on the root logger).